# limit function and integrals

Tags: measure-theory

This time I'm asking you for a revision of an excercise I solved. The problem is:

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ a finite measure space. Take $0\le f\in\mathcal{L}^1(X,\mu)$. If $f_n(x)=f(x)^{1/n}$, calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_Xf_nd\mu$.

My solution:

Let $A,B,C$ and $D$ the sets:

\begin{eqnarray*}
A&=&\{x\in X|f(x)=0\}\\
B&=&\{x\in X|0<f(x)<1\}\\
C&=&\{x\in X|f(x)=1\}\\
D&=&\{x\in X|1<f(x)\}.
\end{eqnarray*}

We note that $X=A\cup B\cup C\cup D$ and these are disjoint sets. As $f_n=f^{1/n}\ge 0$, then the function $m_n:\mathcal{A}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $m_n(Y)=\int_Yf_n\mathrm{d}\mu$ is a measure on $(X,\mathcal{A})$. So, for each $n$, we have

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_Xf_n\mathrm{d}\mu&=&\int_Af_n\mathrm{d}\mu+\int_Bf_n\mathrm{d}\mu+\int_Cf_n\mathrm{d}\mu+\int_Df_n\mathrm{d}\mu\nonumber\\
&=&\int_X1_Af_n\mathrm{d}\mu+\int_X1_Bf_n\mathrm{d}\mu+\int_X1_Cf_n\mathrm{d}\mu+\int_X1_Df_n\mathrm{d}\mu....(1)
\end{eqnarray}

From this, we deduce that if the limit in each member of the sum of (1) exist like a real number, we can calculate $\lim\int_Xf_n\mathrm{d}\mu$ as their sum.

So, on one hand, for $A$, $\int_X1_Af_n(x)\mathrm{d}\mu=0$, since $f_n(x)=f(x)^{1/n}=0$ en $A$. Thus 
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X1_Af_n\mathrm{d}\mu=0....(2)\end{eqnarray}

In a similar way, for $C$, $\int_X1_Cf_n(x)\mathrm{d}\mu=\mu(C)$, since $1_C(x)f_n(x)=f(x)^{1/n}=1$ for $x\in C$ and 0 in other case. Thus 
\begin{eqnarray}\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X1_Cf_n\mathrm{d}\mu=\mu(C)....(3)\end{eqnarray}

For $B$: If $x\in B$, then $0<f(x)<1$. Indeed, $0<f(x)^{\frac{1}{n}}<f(x)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}<1$. Thus $0\le 1_Bf_1\le 1_Bf_2\le 1_Bf_3\le\cdots\le 1_B$. So, for each $x\in X$, the numeric sequence $\{1_B(x)f_n(x)\}$ is increasing and bounded one. Then, it converges to a function $g_B:X\to\mathbb{R}$. But it is easily to see that $g_B=1_B$. In summary: $0\le 1_B(x)f_n(x)\nearrow 1_B(x)$.

Finally, by Monotone Increasing Theorem:

\begin{eqnarray}
\mu(B)&=&\int_X1_B\mathrm{d}\mu\nonumber\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X1_Bf_n\mathrm{d}\mu....(4) 
\end{eqnarray}

On the other hand, for $D$, we note that if $x\in D$, then $1<f(x)$. So, $1<f(x)^{\frac{1}{n+1}}<f(x)^{\frac{1}{n}}<f(x)^1=f(x)$. Therefore $0\le f-1_Df_1\le f-1_Df_2\le\cdots\le f-1_D$. Applying the same idea for $B$ to the sequence $\{f-1_Df_n\}$, we have $0\le f-1_Df_n\nearrow f-1_D$.

Then, by Monotone Convergence Theorem:

\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X1_Df_n\mathrm{d}\mu&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}-\int_Xf-1_Df_n-f\mathrm{d}\mu\nonumber\\
&=&-\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_Xf-1_Df_n\mathrm{d}\mu+\int_Xf\mathrm{d}\mu\nonumber\\
&=&-\int_Xf-1_D\mathrm{d}\mu+\int_Xf\mathrm{d}\mu\mbox{ (here we use the MCT)}\nonumber\\
&=&-\int_Xf\mathrm{d}\mu+\mu(D)+\int_Xf\mathrm{d}\mu\nonumber\\
&=&\mu(D)....(5)
\end{eqnarray}

Using (2),(3), (4) and (5), we conclude in (1) that
\begin{eqnarray*}\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_Xf_n(x)\mathrm{d}\mu=\mu(B)+\mu(C)+\mu(D),\end{eqnarray*}

q.e.d.

My question is: How I used the finite property of the measure?

Greetings and thankyou for your answers.

Comment: I don't see any place that you used it, but as my measure theory is rather rusty, I don't suggest putting much confidence in that. One thing I do suggest is that $D$ could be more simply handled by noting that $f_n \searrow 1$. The MCT works in both directions.

Comment: Hello Paul. I thought about your hint about the MCT, but in my class We have not studied this extended version and it use means that I before should to prove it in my solution as a lemma

Comment: Not a hint. Just a suggestion to simplify things a bit. It is called the "Monotone CT" instead of the "Increasing CT" for a reason. It works for decreasing sequences too.. And I really suspect your book mentions this, as it is immediate from the increasing case.